# Match all GNU C SIMD vector extension types in clang/gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, simd, sfinae

The objective is to write a type trait with the following signature:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_vector : std::true_type / std::false_type
```

such that you can use `is_vector<T>::value` in SFINAE signatures. How do I properly detect whether a type is `__attribute__((__vector_size(<some_vector_width>)) <some_built-in_type>` in GCC/clang?

I looked through [the LLVM documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#vectors-and-extended-vectors) but couldn't see any built-ins to detect this.  The [GNU C documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html) similarly only documents it as a C extension, not mentioning C++.

The backup plan is to specialize the template for each permutation but that really doesn't sound nice.

Comment: you can write a partial specialization. There may be known gcc bugs in this area though.

Comment: It would probably be easier to wrap all such types in a known template class, then match that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a type trait to check if it's one of these vector types. It was a bit tricky finding a way to do it, but using one of the built-in functions that operates on the vectors seems to work.

In this gcc example, I use `__builtin_convertvector` to try to convert the vector type to the same vector type. If it's not a vector type, SFINAE will select the `test()` function that returns `false_type`. If it is one of the vector types, it'll select the `test()` function that returns `true_type`.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct is_vector {
    static std::false_type test(...);

    template<class B>
    static auto test(B) ->
        decltype(__builtin_convertvector(std::declval<B>(), B), std::true_type{});

    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test(std::declval<T>()))::value;
};

template<class T>
static constexpr bool is_vector_v = is_vector<T>::value;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vvzr5c5sz)

Comment: Also works with clang on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Pje6qnd1W.  Nice, I didn't know about that builtin.  I was thinking of something like a `(__m128i)vec` cast, which neither GCC nor clang allow from `int`, but they also don't allow it from different-width vectors.  (Clang allows conversion between same-width vectors of different types without cast, like `__m128i` (made of long long) vs. `__m128` (made of float).  Unless you use `-flax-vector-conversions`, which strangely makes this more strict.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks! I didn't even know about any of these vector types before (I've never done any SIMD stuff) so I spent a long time trying to get a template match where the vector size was one of the template parameters but that failed completely. I then noticed this function by pure chance and thought I would give that a go. :-)

Comment: This worked perfectly, great trick!

Comment: @Shaggi Glad it worked! You're welcome!